# Ljava.lang.String is displayed when I accesed param in thymeleaf Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem while accessing the page parameter in thymeleaf. 
Please see my below code :

```
<input type="hidden" name="resetKey" th:value="${param.key}"/>
```

I am trying to access parameter key from query string and send it as hidden parameter to the server.

After page loads, it is displayed like below :

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="[Ljava.lang.String;@b1fd0f9">
```

I want to send the key back to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: That is no string but the string representation of a String array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question did not update properly. I updated with the code now. Please review now.

Comment: It seems that `param.key`is still an array and the answer of holmis83 is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to print a multi-value, a String array. To print the first value:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="resetKey" th:value="${param.key[0]}"/>
```

Or this should work too:

```
<input type="hidden" name="resetKey" th:value="${#request.getParameter('key')}"/>
```

Source: [Spring MVC and Thymeleaf: how to access data from templates](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)